# ts instantiate a class passed as parameter

Tags: typescript

I was trying to implement a neat way to build multiple Plants (inspired by plants vs zombies). To make it easy to add more plant Types I wanted to make the cost and dmg of the plant static so I can set it once for all Plants of this type.

In this case I have only one Plant (Sunflower), now I would like to instantiate the Sunflowerplant. In the build method in the Cell class.

When doing it like this I get the error:
`Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.` which is understandable for me. So is there a way to only be able to pass non abstract classes which extend from Plant as a Parameter for the `build()` methode or do I have to implement some sort of `if (!c isAbstract)`

```
abstract class Plant {
  public static dmg: number;
  public static cost: number;

  constructor(cell: Cell) {
    this.cell = cell;
  }

  cell: Cell;
}

// I would like to create more Plants like this
class Sunflower extends Plant {
  public static dmg = 0;
  public static cost = 50;
  cell: Cell;

  constructor(cell: Cell) {
    super(cell);
  }
}

class Cell {
  build(c: typeof Plant) {
    if (c.cost <= game.money) {
      this.plant = new c(this); //Cannot create an instance of an abstract class.
      game.money -= c.cost;
    }
  }
}

// this is how I would build plants.
let c = new Cell();
c.build(Sunflower);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class Cell {
    
  build<T extends Plant>(plant: (new (cell:Cell) => T)) {
    const plantInstance = new plant(this); 
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-MFwt0wlFCAAtEFOWcIHtwtoQTdUm5PBgvAh3MMMtlcvkEMGG+qIG7iD7jSqyZDLCYgR1vE22CZegMhiMoECgA)

Comment: Is there a way to acsess `plant.cost` or `T.cost`?

Comment: @0brine I think you could do `plantInstance.constructor.cost` but typescript might complain - the javascript will work though

Comment: To be honest - I probably wouldnt make those properties static!

Comment: Oh, havent thought about that, readonly would make way more sence